# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

Установил mariadb-server-10.1 на Debian9.5. Но появляется ошибка `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` при попытке подключится либо через терминал, либо через phpmyadmin. Пароль при установке на запрашивало пароль для root. По этому по урокам в гугле попытался менять пароль, но также безуспешно. Пытался давать все права для root, записывать в plugin для root unix_socket, но ошибка не меняется. Создавал нового юзера, давал все права, но ошибка такая же, но только root на имя новго юзера меняется. MariaDb переустанавливал много раз. В mysql_secure_installation тоже не пускает.

Comment: пароли в phpmyadmin и roota в базе совпадают? проверить есть [гайд](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Пароли совпадают.

Comment: Не знаю как с марией, но mysql сейчас при установке генерирует пароль рута в /root/.mysql_secret. Посмотрите там

Comment: Файла .mysql_secret нету

Comment: Из под рута в терминале пускает?
> sudo mysql